# Not sure what windows Path command is doing?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, classpath

So I'm not sure exactly what this command is doing - it looks like it was set up edit the path variable.

I need to run it for a class. Unfortunately it's not well documented so I want to make sure: will this mess up my PATH variable? If so, how do I backup my PATH variable first? (My OS is windows 10.)

```
rem myauto for java

path=.;c:\;"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin";c:\javaHW
set classpath=.;c:/;"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8._66\bin\lib";c:\javaJW
```

Comment: There is no real need to back up `PATH`, as restarting `cmd` will restore it. If you don't want to do this, you can `set savepath=%path%`, then use `path %savepath%` to restore, but there may be other variables which have been set or changed which restarting is the easiest way to restore. I presume that the two obvious differences in the directories on the second line are typing errors.

Comment: That tells me what I need to know, posting that as the answer would be acceptable: It does reset `PATH`, but only temporarily, and can be reset simply by restarting command prompt. Thanks, @AFH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need to back up `PATH`: restarting `cmd` will restore it, along with any other variables which have been set or changed by other files in the application suite.

If you don't want to do this, you can simply save `PATH` in another variable:

```
savepath=%path%
```

You can equally simply restore it with:

```
set path=%savepath%
```

or, more simply (a blank or equals sign can be used after `path`):

```
path %savepath%
```

Of course, other variables will not be reset.